# How do i make a Javascript array global?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Forgive me I need a little help, I don't have a coders brain, actually i'm impressed I got this far but now I need a little help.

I'm trying to build a player to load html files into a div from an xml file and then be able to navigate through the pages with previous and next buttons. So far I have managed to load the xml, convert it to an array and load the first page but when I click on the previous and next buttons I get "pages is undefined".

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var i = 0;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "studyguide/new_course.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {          
            pages = parseXml(xml)
            doStuff(pages);
            loadFirstPage(pages);
        } // END success
    }); //END ajax

    function parseXml(xml) {
        var pages = [];
        $(xml).find("page").each(function() {
            pages.push({
                title: $(this).find("title").text(), 
                url: $(this).find("url").text()
            }); // END .push
        }); // END .each
        return pages;
    } // END parseXML

    function doStuff(pages) {
        //Do some javascript stuff with the response
        alert(pages[0].title);
        alert(pages[0].url);
    } // END doStuff

    function loadFirstPage(pages){
        //alert(pages[i].url);
        $('#displayResults').html('<img src="../images/495.gif" />');
        $( "#displayResults" ).load(pages[i].url, function() {
        }) //END .load
    }; //END loadFirstPage

    function loadPage(pages){
        //alert(pages[i].url);
        $('#displayResults').html('<img src="../images/495.gif" />');
        $( "#displayResults" ).load(pages[i].url, function() {
        }) //END .load
    };// END loadPage

    $('#prev').bind('click', function(pages) {
        i--;
        //alert(i);
        loadPage();
    }) //END click

    $('#next').bind('click', function(pages) {
        i++;
        //alert(i);
        loadPage();
    }) // END click

}); // END ready
```

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<course>
    <section name = "Section One">
        <page>
            <title>Page 1</title>
            <url>studyguide/page1.html</url> 
            <instructions></instructions>   
        </page> 
        <page>
            <title>Page 2</title>
            <url>studyguide/page2.html</url> 
            <instructions></instructions>   
        </page>
        <page>
            <title>Page 3</title>
            <url>studyguide/page3.html</url> 
            <instructions></instructions>   
        </page>
    </section>
    <section name = "Section Two">
        <page>
            <title>Page 1</title>
            <url>studyguide/page4.html</url> 
            <instructions></instructions>   
        </page>
        <page>
            <title>Page 2</title>
            <url>studyguide/page5.html</url> 
            <instructions></instructions>   
        </page>
    </section>
</course>
```

So I have 2 Questions, firstly how do I make the array global so it can be used by the loadPage function. And second, is there a better way of doing this in the first place. The xml could contain 5 pages or 100 pages so I want to keep it dynamic.

Thanks

Thanks for your help guys. I made some changes and now I get "pages[I] is undefined. Sorry i'm not a coder by nature so you have to go slowly with me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var i = 0;
    var pages = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "studyguide/new_course.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {          
            pages = parseXml(xml)
            doStuff(pages);
            loadFirstPage(pages);
        } // END success
    }); //END ajax

    function parseXml(xml) {
        //var pages = [];
        $(xml).find("page").each(function() {
            pages.push({
                title: $(this).find("title").text(), 
                url: $(this).find("url").text()
            }); // END .push
        }); // END .each
        return pages;
    } // END parseXML

    function doStuff(pages) {
        //Do some javascript stuff with the response
        alert(pages[0].title);
        alert(pages[0].url);
    } // END doStuff

    function loadFirstPage(pages){
        //alert(pages[i].url);
        $('#displayResults').html('<img src="../images/495.gif" />');
        $( "#displayResults" ).load(pages[i].url, function() {
        }) //END .load
    }; //END loadFirstPage

    function loadPage(pages){
        //alert(pages[i].url);
        $('#displayResults').html('<img src="../images/495.gif" />');
        $( "#displayResults" ).load(pages[i].url, function() {
        }) //END .load
    };// END loadPage

    $('#prev').bind('click', function(pages) {
        i--;
        //alert(i);
        loadPage(pages);
    }) //END click

    $('#next').bind('click', function(pages) {
        i++;
        alert(i);
        loadPage(pages);
    }) // END click

}); // END ready
```

Comment: Use `window.varname = ...`.

Comment: just declare the array where you declare `i`: `var i = 0, pages=[];`. Don't forget to remove it from the parseXML function

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question, if you don't put a `var` in front of the variable declaration it will become global (on the window object).  Doing this is generally considered a bad idea.  I would personally probably declare the variable in your `ready` function then use it for your other functions within that scope.

Another observation here is that you set up your `loadPage` function with a parameter, however then you aren't passing it anything in your call to it.

I think your approach works just fine though.

Comment: I just added alert(pages.length); to the doStuff function and it resulted in a popup with the number 5 in it which is correct but when I added the same alert to the loadpages function I got the same alert but the number is now 1?

Comment: @user2961753 would it be possible for you to create a JSFiddle?  That would make it so much easier to see your issue.

Comment: Fixed it! Just removed "pages" from function loadPage(pages) and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2961753 You should consider accepting this as the answer to the question.